# How do I use state and the value of an object's keys to dynamically style in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, axios

Im using CRA and Axios here, the code will be included.
Problem: I want to make a stock chart, a very basic one. it should function as such, on load component mounts and axios makes a call to the static api (for now) to populate the chart of exchange rates. as a basic learning point for me to dive deeper im stuck on how to use the value of each key in the object to make it red if its worht less than a usd and green if its worth more. I know how to refer to the styling in line but dont know how to access the value of the keys in state setting context.. thanks
postman response from api looks like such and populates in the container properly

```
{
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "GBP": 0.7775366251,
        "HKD": 7.8246518358,
        "IDR": 14084.997287032,
        "ILS": 3.4664496292,
        "DKK": 6.7577319588,
        "INR": 71.6865617652,
        "CHF": 0.994212335,
        "MXN": 19.3951890034,
        "CZK": 23.0719840839,
        "SGD": 1.3629951167,
        "THB": 30.1953336951,
        "HRK": 6.7249954784,
        "EUR": 0.9043226623,
        "MYR": 4.1710074154,
        "NOK": 9.1411647676,
        "CNY": 7.0387050099,
        "BGN": 1.768674263,
        "PHP": 50.8545849159,
        "PLN": 3.8865075059,
        "ZAR": 14.7149574968,
        "CAD": 1.327455236,
        "ISK": 123.259178875,
        "BRL": 4.188189546,
        "RON": 4.3173268222,
        "NZD": 1.5586905408,
        "TRY": 5.7079942123,
        "JPY": 108.545849159,
        "RUB": 63.6969614759,
        "KRW": 1178.395731597,
        "USD": 1.0,
        "AUD": 1.4728703201,
        "HUF": 302.3060227889,
        "SEK": 9.6097847712
    },
    "date": "2019-11-22"
}
```

React code

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './currency.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from'axios'



class Currency extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            subject: "react state",
            instructor: "Lukas",
            purpose: "to make stacks",
            data: {},
            isGreater: false,
            isLess: false,
            isSpecial: false
            // queryUrl: "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD"
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.rates.hasSpecialStuff) {
                    this.setState({
                        data: response.data.rates,
                        isSpecial: true
                    })
                }
                this.setState({
                    data: response.data.rates
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Container>
                    <div id="ratesDiv">
                         <h2> Current Exchange Rates</h2>
                        {Object.keys(this.state.data).map(key => <p className={'rateP'} style={this.state.isSpecial ? {backgroundColor: "red"} : {backgroundColor: "transparent"}}>{`${key}, ${this.state.data[key]}`}</p>)}
                    </div>
                </Container>



            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Currency;
```

Comment: What's the `.hasSpecialStuff ` property, it's not in the data, not sure what it's referring to. Also, when rendering it why don't you just use the value as the style's condition check, i.e. instead of `this.state.isSpecial ?...` just use `Number(this.state.data[key]) < 1 ?...`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code **`isSpecial`** should remain always either **`true`** or **`false`**, so my understanding is that it shouldn't be part of the condition to make everything red or transparent rather you should focus on USD which is also your requirement too. You can try this following code:

```
     {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((key, i) => (
        <p
          key={i}
          className={"rateP"}
          style={
            parseFloat(this.state.data[key]) <
            parseFloat(this.state.data["USD"])
              ? { backgroundColor: "red" }
              : { backgroundColor: "transparent" }
          }
        >{`${key}, ${this.state.data[key]}`}</p>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set the style as below

```
  {Object.keys(this.state.data).map(s =>
            <p
              style={this.state.data[s] > 1 ?
                { backgroundColor: 'green' } : { backgroundColor: 'red' }
              }>
              {s}, {this.state.data[s]}
            </p>)}
```